# Variable not defined : AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, controller, angularjs-scope

I'm pretty new to Angular JS, but I was making a service to get information from a JSON:

This is the service code:

```
var staffServices = angular.module('staffServices', ['ngResource']);

staffServices.factory('Staff', function($resource){
return $resource('/api/staff/1', {}, {
 query: {method:'GET', params: {}, isArray:false}
});
});
```

Controller

```
staffApp.controller('StaffCtrl', function($scope, Staff) {
Staff.query(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $scope.staff = data;
      console.log(staff);
  });
```

However, when I run the app, I'm able to see the "data" as an Object but I'm not able to asign it to the scope variable, I get the following "Error: staff is not defined".

Thanks for all your answers !

Comment: What is the line that gives you the error?

Comment: should be console.log($scope.staff);

Comment: @klode Put that in a formal answer; I think you nailed it.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
console.log(staff); // this prints the var staff, which is undefined
```

should be

```
console.log($scope.staff); // this prints the staff property of $scope
```